# popup.js не принимает сообщения Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Пробую так
**background.js**

принимаю сообщения от popup.js (работает)

```
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log('chrome.runtime.onMessage');
            console.log(request);
            if (request&&request.method&&request.action) {
                if($.isFunction(getLr()[request.method][request.action])) {
                    sendResponse(getLr()[request.method][request.action](request.data?request.data:undefined));
                } else {
                    sendResponse(getLr()[request.method][request.action]);
                }
            }
        });
```

высылаю дынные в popup (**не работает**)

```
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){
        for(let t in tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[t].id, $.extend({}, {method: method}, data), callback);
        }
    });
```

**popup.js**

высылаю в background.js (работает)

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: method, action: action, data: data}, callback);
```

принимаю от background (**не работает**)

```
window.onload = function () {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log('chrome.runtime.onMessage');
    });
};
```

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы принять данные в **popup** - окно должно отображаться (читайте *существовать*).

Для отправки сообщения попапу необходимо использовать метод `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.